# How to create custom logout functionlity in laravel

Tags: logout, laravel-5.7

How to create logout functionlity in laravel. I want it to redirect to some other page instead of home page which is default in laravel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

overrid this method in  App/Http/Controllers/Auth/loginController

```
/**
 * The user has logged out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/anywhere');
}
```